# How to use sName property in Jquery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

From the server i get data in json format, and i am using the below code to render it on the page. But unable to set the  attribute  "name" on the columns i.e., cells.  Is sName the right property i should use to set "name" attribute for every Cell.
Here is my Datables code.

```
$('#' + self.dom.tableID).dataTable({
            "asStripeClasses": [self.ui.rowClass],
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "sDom": "tip",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "name", "sClass": self.ui.nameCellClass, "sWidth": "35%", "sTitle": "Name" },
                { "mDataProp": "email", "sTitle": "Email"},
                { "mDataProp": "phone", "sTitle": "Phone"},
                { "mDataProp": "organizationName", "sTitle": "Organization"},
                { "mDataProp": "organizationRenewDate", "sTitle": "Expires on", "sWidth": "100px", "sType": "date"}

            ],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sZeroRecords": "No matching members found."
            }
        });
```

By the way i need "name" attribute on each cell to send the data back to the server side code.

Comment: What crappy plug is that? Those are horrible key names! LoL, but seriously, that plugin needs work. Is it a must? there a several different ways to achieve what you are trying too.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: It's a quite useful table plugin for jQuery. The configuration key names are in hungarian notation... not my favorite style, but they do the trick. I'd invite you to write a better one though if it's really that bad ;)

Comment: @BLSully if i get the freetime sometime soon, I might have to take you up on that. LoL. From what I just looked at on the API tho, it looks like you're doing everything right. Just hope someone with experience on this plug hits you up. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to create inputs so when you post the form, the data gets sent back to the server?

In this case, you'll need to use `fnRender` (old way) or `mRender` (new way) to write input elements into your cell. Something like the following should get you on the right track:

```
{
    mDataProp: "name",
    sTitle: "Name",
    mRender: function(data, type, full) {
        switch(type){
            case 'display':
                return '<input type="text" name="name[]" value="' + data + '" />';
            default:
                return data;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, I'm going to guess you need something more like this:

```
fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    //replace 1 with whichever cell you need
    $('td:nth-child(1)', nRow).attr('name', "WhateverNameYouWant");
}
```

Comment: yes, am creating input cell, but that is taken care by replacing the cell with a "input type=text"  on double click event.  First i need to figure out a way to display the cell with  name attribute while rendering. Is it possible to do that with mRender ?

Comment: No, you need to use `fnRowCallback` to modify the generated html. Please see: http://datatables.net/ref